# how to check an array has cards in ascending order or two cards the same or three cards the same etc

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I was making a poker simulation when I got stuck on how to make python check an array for pairs, straights, three of a kinds etc. i have made my code so each array of cards generates a second array with the stores value for each card. 
For example

```
a=[1,3,4,2,5,8,1]  b=[2,2,4,7,10] c=[5,6,5,5,5]
```

how would I check if a had at least 5 consecutive numbers (a straight) if b had at least 2 numbers equal to each other (a pair) and if c had 4.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the hand.  This makes it easy to check for a straight, as you need the five numbers in sequence.

For N of a kind, walk through the list and see how many of each item you have.  For instance:

```
for pos in range(len(hand)):
    card_count = hand.count(hand[pos])
    if card_count >= 2:
        print "Hand has", card_count, hand[pos], "'s"
```

I haven't given away all the details here -- this will print twice for each pair, 3 times for 3-of-a-kind, etc.  I assume that you're asking most for the basic list methods you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough to get you started.

```
def check_hand(_hand_):
    last_c = ''
    straight = 0
    # This is illustrative, you can use this to return
    # the greatest hand one could have
    for card_value, number_of_occurences in _hand_.iteritems():
        if number_of_occurences == 2:
            print("We have a 2 of a kind")
        elif number_of_occurences == 3:
            print("We have a 3 of a kind")
        elif number_of_occurences == 4:
            print("We have a 4 of a kind")

        if last_c == '':
            last_c = card_value
        else:
            if card_value - last_c == 1:
                straight += 1
            last_c = card_value

    if straight >= 4:
        print("we have a straight")

a = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 1]
b = [2, 2, 4, 7, 10]
c = [5, 6, 5, 5, 5]

# nifty way of assigning a dictionary with how many
# occurrences of a number in a list, and sorting it
check = {
    'a': dict((i, a.count(i)) for i in sorted(a)),
    'b': dict((i, b.count(i)) for i in sorted(b)),
    'c': dict((i, c.count(i)) for i in sorted(c)),
}

for which, hand in check.iteritems():
    print "Hand: " + which
    check_hand(hand)
```